# How to write serializable objects in XML files without overwrite the file? SAXParseException

Tags: java, xml, parsing

As the title suggests, I want to write objects to the file without overwrite the same file. 
The problem is that when I try do write an object to the file I receive the following message:

"org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file. Continuing ..."

And then nothing goes to the file. If I try to serializable in other type of ile, like .ser, I get an error saying that it wasn't possible write to the file.

```
package application.library.crud.kvlth;

import java.beans.XMLDecoder;
import java.beans.XMLEncoder;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Create {
    private static XMLEncoder output;
    private static XMLDecoder inpt;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        openFile();
        addRecords();
        closeFile();
    }

    public static void openFile() {
            try {
                output = new XMLEncoder(
                        new BufferedOutputStream(
                                new FileOutputStream("library.xml")));

            } catch (IOException ioException) {
                System.err.println("Error opening file. Terminating.");
                System.exit(1);
            }

    }

    public static void addRecords() throws IOException {
        inpt = new XMLDecoder(
                new BufferedInputStream(
                        new FileInputStream("library.xml")));

        ArrayList<Book> books;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.printf("%s%n%s%n? ",
                "Enter ISBN number, Author's name, Book's Title.",
                "Enter end-of-file indicator to end input.");

        while (input.hasNext()) {

            try {
                Book record = new Book(input.nextLine(),
                        input.nextLine(), input.nextLine());

                books = (ArrayList<Book>) inpt.readObject(); /*here 
                at my IDE (Intellij) it shows me the following 
                message: "Unchecked cast: 'java.lang.Object' to 
               'java.util.ArrayList'"*/
                inpt.close();
                books.add(record);
                output.writeObject(books);

            } catch (NullPointerException e){
                e.getStackTrace();

            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException arrayExc){

            }
            System.out.println("? ");
        }
    }

    public static void closeFile() {
        if (output != null)
            output.close();
    }
}
```

[This is what it shows to me. It continues running but never write to the file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWCS9.png)

Comment: Do you get the SAXParseException when you try to read the file? Could be that your library.xml file is empty or malformed. Ideally you should separate the file reading and writing logic out of your input loop.

You haven't shown how you open `output` for writing, it would be helpful to include that.

Comment: Hey @Geoff thx for the answer. I appreciate it
So I edited the post and included the whole code .
I get the SAXParseException right after I send an Object to the fille and then it shows me the message. The application continues running, but it never writes to the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to `write objects to the file without overwrite the same file`. If you want to read a file, insert some elements in the middle, then output the rest of the file you either have to read it in memory then write it all out again, or write to a temporary file where you are doing your insert and then copy the temporary file over the original.

So in your case, change your 'output' file to the temporary, then copy it back over the original when you are done outputting it.

**Example of streaming process:**
For example, if your input is 
input.xml:

```
<books>
    <Book>Genesis</Book>
    <Bool>Leviticus</Book>
</books>
```

you would read elements until you reach the point where you want to add a new book, writing to output

```
read
    <books>

write
    <books>

read
        <Book>Genesis</Book>

write
        <Book>Genesis</Book>
```

then append the book you want to add

```
write
        <Book>Exodus</Book>
```

then continue with the rest

```
read
        <Book>Leviticus</Book>

write
        <Book>Leviticus</Book>

read
        </books>

write
        </books>
```

Resulting in output.xml:

```
<books>
    <Book>Genesis</Book>
    <Bool>Exodus</Book>
    <Bool>Leviticus</Book>
</books>
```

This is a lot easier working with SAX rather than something which wraps up all the books in an array.
You probably don't need to do this unless you are processing large amounts of data.

Comment: So, I don't even need the ArrayList here? It's just writing to the temporary file and then put it in the original? And how can I insert some elements in the middle of a file?

Comment: @user9954844 You can write everything in the original file up to the insertion point to the temporary file, then write the data you want to insert to the temporary file, then write everything in the original file after the insertion point to the temporary file. Or you can read everything into the array list, close the original file and write the data in the list back to it. You don't need both.

Comment: I'm having problem to understand the "up to the insertion point to the temporary file". How can I specify this to my program?  Sorry, I'm a newbie.